# on event not handle jquery

Tags: jquery, events

I don't realy understand why my on event didn't works with jquery. 
The html is generated after the handler but it must works:

```
Calendar = function(){
    this.init = function(elem, path, callback){
    this.elem = elem;
    $.ajax({
        url:path,
        type:'GET',
        context: this,
        success:function(data){
            this.data = data;
            callback();
        }
    })
}

    this.generateBase = function(){
        var base = '<div class="row-fluid" >';
        base += '<div class="span3" id="month" ></div>';
        base += '<div class="span9" id="week" ></div>';
        base += '</div>';
        $(this.elem).html(base);
    }
}

$('#month').on('click',function(){
alert('aa');
});
```

And I use it like that

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(document).ready(function(){
    var calendar = new Calendar();
    calendar.init('#calendar',path,function(){
        calendar.generateBase();
    });
});
</script>
```

I really don't understand why there is no alert on click

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delegate event to parent of dynamically added element, if you do know parent to can delegate to document.

```
$(document).on('click', '#month',function(){
   alert('aa');
});
```

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$(document).on('click','#month',function(){
alert('aa');
});
```